# How to require typeclass instance in data definition

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Assume I have a type like this:

```
data Graph vertex = Graph {
  vertices :: [vertex],
  edgelist :: [(vertex, [vertex])]
}
```

But I would like to have a typeclass constraint on the type variable vertex, I was attempting to do it like it's done with typeclass definitions:

```
data (Eq vertex) => Graph vertex = Graph {
  vertices :: [vertex],
  edgelist :: [(vertex, [vertex])]
}
```

But that produces a syntax error `Illegal datatype context (use DatatypeContexts)`. What is the correct way to achieve this? Or is it not possible?

Comment: "DatatypeContexts" was a "feature" supported in earlier versions of Haskell that was removed because it doesn't do what you think and is essentially always a mistake.  It can be quite useful to omit the constraint even when it seems that it would always be needed anyway.  For example, you can make your Graph type into a Functor, but not if you added that constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is to use [GADTs](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT):

```
{-# language GADTs #-}
data Graph vertex where
  Graph :: (Eq vertex) => { vertices :: [vertex], edgelist :: [(vertex, [vertex])] } -> Graph vertex
```

this will ensure that you will always have `Eq vertex` in scope **when you pattern match on the `Graph` constructor**.

Answer (score 5):

The Haskell convention is to never put constraints on data types. Instead, put them on the functions operating on the data types. This allows you to put the constraints only on those functions that actually need them.